# Is there anyway to know at which card "add comment" has clicked using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to add a comment section to my web app however, I want to know which book its "add comment" has clicked I'm thinking about getting the book's ID.

Here is my python

```
@app.route("/comment", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def comment():
    if request.method == "POST":
     if not request.form.get("comment"):
        return apology("must provide comment", 400)
     book = request.form.get("book_id")
     print(session["user_id"])
     print(book)
     id = session["user_id"]
     print(id)
     user = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=?", id)
     db.execute("INSERT INTO comment (comment, user,book_id) VALUES(?, ?,?)", comment, user,book)
     return render_template ("index.html")

    else:
        return render_template ("comment.html")
```

Here is my html code

```
<form action="/comment" method="get">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row g-3">
        {% for book in books %}
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="{{book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}}">

               <div  class="card-body">
               <h5 style="color:red" class="card-title">{{book.volumeInfo.title}}</h5>
               <p style="color:blue" class="card-text">{{book.volumeInfo.authors}}</p>
               <p style="visibility:hidden" class="card-text">{{book.id}}</p>
               <input name="book" style="visibility:hidden" class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" name="book_id" value="{{book.id}}" type="text">
               <a href="{{book.volumeInfo.infoLink}}" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
               <button value="{{book.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">add comment</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This HTML element

```
<input name="book" style="visibility:hidden" class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" name="book_id" value="{{book.id}}" type="text">
```

has two different values for attribute `name`, please try removing one of them, that is

```
<input name="book_id" style="visibility:hidden" class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" value="{{book.id}}" type="text">
```

and then write if you can access `book_id` properly in your Flask application. As side if you need to have `input` invisble to user you might use [`type="hidden"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp) rather than tinker with styling, in this case

```
<input name="book_id" value="{{book.id}}" type="hidden">
```

Comment: I have done that thanks, but the problem is when I click "add comment" I can see in the URL all the IDs have the same name which is "book" how can I after clicking on a book's "add comment" just give that id the name book